# WifiManager not working for Android Q API 29 using Java?

Tags: java, android

In my case, I have WifiManager class, When I changed target version API 28 to 29 then its getting many lines of code deprecated. setWifienable, WifiConfiguration, getConfigureNetworks, SSID and networkInfo, etc many method deprecated. How to remodify for Android Q, Please provide some sample.

Comment: The [documentation for `WiFiManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager) contains notes about the deprecated methods and the replacements (where such replacements exist).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you so much for your info btw I am new for this can you please update my code? I am trying from a long time but can't able to understand.

Comment: @CommonsWare anything help from your side?